# Replicate Excel Formula in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, formula

I am trying to put together an IF statement on Power BI similar to what I have managed to do in Excel.
Looking for Journey Order to add 1 for ever duplicate counted in the Journey Key Column.

If( Journey Key = Journey Key, Journey Order + 1, 1 )

Example = IF( A3 = A2, B2+1, 1)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFXlF.png)

Is there any DAX formula within Power BI that would replicate the above?

Comment: Have a search on a 'running countif' in powerbi. Pretty sure you are not the first one trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If It is acceptable for you, I can recommend an alternative solution: For this, You need an index column: Let's say you have a table like this:

```
Index   Journey Key
1        WI1234
2        WI1234
3        WI4321
4        WI4321
5        WI4321
```

Then you can create a DAX measure using this code:

```
Journey Order = CALCULATE(
    COUNT(JourneyTable[Journey Key]),
FILTER(
    ALL(JourneyTable[Index]),
        JourneyTable[Index] <= MAX(JourneyTable[Index])
)
)
```

[image: TETA]